# How to generate a payload at runtime for a request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm new to javascript/nodejs and I need to test a payload within limits of 4mb via mocha/nodejs and I've used a function to generate a string of characters of length ~4mb+ to simulate the payload and pass that within the request as payload. However, I'm getting a timeout exception `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`. This is probably because this approach is not valid as the request generation itself is taking too long ... I tried increasing the wait time but in vain.

```js
it('expected: handle request made with payload exceeding REQUEST_LIMIT of 4mb', (done) => {
      chai.request(server).post('/payload').send({ data: payload(4520000) }) // payload exceeds RATE_LIMIT of 4mb
        .set('content-type', 'plain/text')
        .end((error, response) => {
          expect(response).to.have.status(500);
          // return expect(response).to.eventually.have.status(500);
        done();
        });
    });
```

Note that I have also used chai-as-promised and it didn't work for me:

`return expect(response).to.eventually.have.status(500);`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend just returning the promise that `chai.request` produces and not using `done` at all because that will just complicate error handling for you:

```
it('expected: handle request made with payload exceeding REQUEST_LIMIT of 4mb', 
   () => chai.request(server).post('/payload').send({ data: payload(4520000) })
        .set('content-type', 'plain/text')
        .end((error, response) => {
          expect(response).to.have.status(500);
        }));
```

(I've used a "concise body" instead of a "block body" for the arrow function above. The `return` is implied.)

If you need to increase the timeout because payload generation takes too long, you'd have to change the above to a proper `function` and use `this.timeout(....)` to a value large enough.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem as it was on my side and thanks to @Louis for affirming the approach to payload generation at least is acceptable. I had specified the wait timeout in my package.json 'mocha ./tests/ -t 3000' but failed to run 'npm install' to allow the changes to take effect.

```js
it('expected: handle request made with payload exceeding REQUEST_LIMIT of 4mb', (done) => {
      chai.request(server).post('/payload').send({ data: payload(4520000) }) // payload exceeds RATE_LIMIT of 4mb
        .set('content-type', 'plain/text')
        .end((error, response) => {
          expect(response).to.have.status(500);
          done();
        });
    }).timeout(3000);
```

I've removed timeout usage from the package.json and moved it to its respective test-case; courtesy @Louis

Comment: I'm not seeing how `npm install` would change anything to the timeout. I could see how setting a `test` `script` in your `package.json` that hardcodes `mocha ./tests/ -t 3000` and then forgetting to use `npm run...` (or `npm test`) would be a problem. Also, if it were me, I'd still want to increase timeout only locally rather than for the whole suite, unless you really have an entire suite that needs a higher timeout.

Comment: You're right, it should be test-case specific. I've updated the answer with feedback, thanks!